# How to add or remove a task in gradle build under Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

In Android default gradle build flow, there would be tasks run follow the order:

```
:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:checkDebugManifest
:prepareDebugDependencies
:compileDebugAidl
:compileDebugRenderscript
:generateDebugBuildConfig
:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugAssets
:generateDebugResValues
:generateDebugResources
:mergeDebugResources
.......................
```

1. Is that possible to ignore a specific task (ex: mergeDebugResources)?
2. Can I insert a extra task (ex: copy specific file to specific folder)?